# How to resolve Minera cgminer "no devices found" error after installing additional GekkoScience USB-Antsticks?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, mining-software

I successfully completed my first attempt to configure my Raspberry Pi for Bitcoin mining with a GekkoScience USB Antstick and Minera; however, after installing additional Antsticks, my env somehow became corrupted which ultimately lead me to wipe my Raspberry Pi and install a fresh copy of Raspian and reinstalling Minera- my question is this: should I have re-compiled Minera after installing additional Antsticks, as detailed within screenshot below captured from the [Minera](https://getminera.com/) manual-install page?

[image]

I've detailed my Minera install-process within the following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/alexanderjsingleton/28d6553ed2fc276c947e96c342332a26) if that helps clarify- basically, I'd like to avoid any future complications after installing additional Antsticks or miners because more are on the way!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, any hardware additions to an existing Raspberry Pi * Minera environment or any adjustments to the hardware parameters specified in Minera Settings > Manual-options do indeed require recompiling cgminer.  In order to resolve, proceed with the following:

1. `cd /var/www/minera`
2. `sudo nano build_miner.sh`
3. Scroll down to the cgminer config and append `-enable-blockerupter` so the entire line displays `CGMINER_CONFIG="--enable-avalon2 --enable-bflsc --enable-bitforce --enable-bitfury --enable-drillbit --enable-hashfast --enable-icarus --enable-klondike --enable-modminer --enable-blockerupter"`
4. Exit and Write.
5. Run `sudo ./build_miner.sh all`
6. Upon compiling, exit from your host-session, unplug the antsticks, power-cycle the Raspberry Pi and then plug-in antsticks.
7. Log-in to the Raspberry Pi and sign-in to Minera- you should see verifiable success displayed in the Minera Dashboard > Device Tree.